# Rails 3 - .Nil? Redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, null

Pulling my hair out on this one:

I'm trying a simple "redirect to home if there's no session email variable" and when I test for the session variable being `nil` is says it isn't, then the code craps out in the next statement complaining that its `nil`.

Here's the code:

```
def index
  if session[:email].nil?
    redirect_to root_url
  end       
  @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => "email = '"+session[:email]+"'")
end
```

So I run this when session does not exist and `@user` is `nil`, since of course there is no user in the db with a nil email address. But why doesn't it redirect when `session[:email]` is `nil`?. BTW, I've tried exists? and blank? and `== nil` and `== ""` to no avail

Any help would be appreciated. Feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `redirect_to root_url and return unless session[:email]`. The `and return` should do the trick.

As Alex said in the comment, `redirect_to` (and `render`, for that matter) are just method calls and as such do not return control to the calling object.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to remember that `redirect_to` doesn't magically return control to the framework, it's just a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pulling it to a separate variable. This code works for me in rails3:

```
abc = session[:abc]
if !abc.blank?
logger.info "blank"
else
logger.info "not"
end
```

Comment: I did try s = session[:email] then test for s.nil? same issue. Funny as this used to work fine for me in Rails 2

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that

```
def index
  @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => "email = '"+session[:email]+"'")
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Tell me if that did the trick.

Comment: It depends on how `session[:email]` is set and used, but using exceptions for handling a normal situation isn't a good idea generally.